# Refreshing pages in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two html pages one is the main template(index) and other is the welcome page.the content of the maintemplate(i.e index page) is visible on every page .
The index page contains a dropdown and on selection of dropdown,the data on the welcome page changes.
I want to reload the welcome page on the drop down selection
I am using location.reload(),but it reloads the entire page and I want to reload only the welcome page. Can somebody Help...Thanks

Comment: Don't use location.reload(), use ng-view and ng-router, where each of the dropdown selections would change the view.

Comment: Do you want to load `welcome page` again and again or you need to change the content (value) of `welcome page` ?

Comment: the content is based on the selection of dropdown
say If A is selected A iis shows or if B is selected it show B

Answer (score 2):

I would look at using $route.reload.

For example:

```
<select ng-change="refreshPage()"><!-- Your select box content. -->
```

JS:

```
function refreshPage()
{
    $route.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,,I achieved it using $state.reload();.is it the correct way??